# Insert correct timestamp in influxdb using python

Tags: python, time-series, timestamp, influxdb

I have a text file with some measurements. The first 3 lines are just the header containing some information as bellow:

```
# OpenSignals Text File Format. Version 1
# {"EC:1B:BD:62:F6:A2": {"date": "2022-7-22", "time": "10:43:47.162", "label": ["A1", "A2", "ECG"]}}
# EndOfHeader
0   1   512
0   0   500
1   1   512
0   0   525
0   0   516
1   2   499
1   1   501
1   0   512
1   0   496
0   0   525
0   0   525
0   0   512
```

On the second line date and time are the starting  date and time of the measurements.
Starting from the 4th line we have the data with labels A1, A2 and ECG with an interval of 1 millisecond.

The goal is to create a timestamp from the date and time and adding 0 milliseconds for the first line of data , 2 milliseconds for the second line, 3 milliseconds for the third and so on...

Later i want to use thsi timestamp as the index to store the values in an influxdb database. Everything i have tried gives me the following error when trying to write to influxdb:

```
TypeError: Must be DataFrame with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex.
```

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import linecache
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from influxdb import DataFrameClient

bhost='192.168.1.150'
dbport=8086
dbuser='telegraf'
dbpasswd="pass"
dbname='test1'
protocol='line'

#SELECT JSON FROM SECOND LINE
info=(linecache.getline('bio.txt',2))[24:-2]
info_json=json.loads(info)
head_info=info_json["label"]

# load Data and add delta column 
df=pd.read_table('bio.txt',skiprows=3,header=None,names=head_info)

# Date, Time end Delta
df['date']=info_json["date"]
df['time']=info_json["time"]
df.insert(0,'delta',range(0,len(df)))
format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']+ ' '+df['time'], format=format)

# Create Index
df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(date_time_obj+(pd.to_timedelta(df.delta,unit='ms')))
df=df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']))
df = df.drop(['date','time','delta','Datetime'], axis=1)

#save to InfluxDb
client=DataFrameClient(dbhost,dbport,dbuser,dbpasswd,dbname)
client.write_points(dn,"signal",time_precision='ms')
```